# UITableView separator color not changing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a drop-down menu. In this drop-down menu, I have a UIView which the user taps on to drop down a UITableView. In the process of creating it, I tried to change the separator color to clear. However, it's not working. I have tried settings it different colors all to no avail, but for some reason when I try to set its edge inset it works. Can someone help me out?

```
private var selectedBackgroundColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 131/255, green: 43/255, blue: 205/255, alpha: 1.0)
private var unSelectedBackgroundColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 178/255, green: 90/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1.0)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInitializer()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.commonInitializer()
}

private func commonInitializer() {
    self.backgroundColor = self.unSelectedBackgroundColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2

    let shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0xC8, green: 0xC6, blue: 0xC6)
    self.layer.applySketchShadow(color: shadowColor, alpha: 0.5, x: 0, y: 2, blur: 5, spread: 0)

    self.itemTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    self.itemTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.itemTableView.delegate = self
    self.itemTableView.dataSource = self
    self.itemTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.itemTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
    self.itemTableView.backgroundColor = self.unSelectedBackgroundColor

}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {

    self.superview?.addSubview(itemTableView)
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(itemTableView)

    //Drop down table view constraints
    self.itemTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.itemTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.itemTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.tableViewHeight = self.itemTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
}


/**
 Changes the drop down button view and table view to the selected color
 */
private func changeToSelectedBackgroundColor() {
    self.backgroundColor = self.selectedBackgroundColor
    self.itemTableView.backgroundColor = self.selectedBackgroundColor
}

/**
 Changes only the drop down button view to the unselected color. Changes the table view to white
 */
private func changeToUnSelectedBackgroundColor() {
    self.backgroundColor = self.unSelectedBackgroundColor
    self.itemTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.itemTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.retractDropDownList()
}

@objc func buttonTapped() {
    self.flashLabel()
    if isExtended {
        self.retractDropDownList()
    } else {
        self.expandDropDownList()
    }
}

private func expandDropDownList() {
    isExtended = true
    self.delegate?.dropDownViewExtended()
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.tableViewHeight])
    self.tableViewHeight.constant = 150.0
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.tableViewHeight])

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        self.changeToSelectedBackgroundColor()
        self.itemTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
        self.itemTableView.center.y += self.itemTableView.frame.height/2

    }, completion: nil)
}

private func retractDropDownList() {
    isExtended = false
    self.delegate?.dropDownViewRetracted()
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.tableViewHeight])
    self.tableViewHeight.constant = 0.0
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.tableViewHeight])


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        self.changeToUnSelectedBackgroundColor()
        self.itemTableView.center.y -= self.itemTableView.frame.height/2
        self.itemTableView.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2

    }, completion: nil)

}
```

}